# Get values and keys in json object using Json.Net C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Hi there I have json that looks like this:

```
{
    "Id": " 357342524563456678",
    "title": "Person",
    "language": "eng",
    "questionAnswer": [
        {
            "4534538254745646.1": {
                "firstName": "Janet",
                "questionNumber": "1.1"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I have written some code that loops over the objects in the `questionAnswer` array and then gets the name of the object which is `4534538254745646.1`. Now Im trying to save the key of each Item and the value aswell but I am only managing to get the value.

How would I do this, here is my code:

```
JToken entireJson = JToken.Parse(json);
JArray inner = entireJson["questionAnswer"].Value<JArray>();


foreach(var item in inner)
{
     JProperty questionAnswerDetails = item.First.Value<JProperty>();
     //This line gets the name, which is fine
     var questionAnswerSchemaReference = questionAnswerDetails.Name;
     var properties = questionAnswerDetails.Value.First;

     //This only gets Janet
     var key = properties.First;
     var value = properties.Last;                                      
}
```

So at the moment Im only able to get Janet, But I also want the firstname field. I want to then take this and add to a dictionary i.e.

```
Dictionary<string, string> details = new Dictionary<string, string>();
//suedo
foreach(var item in questionAnswerObjects)
details.Add(firstName, Janet);
//And then any other things found below this
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So Here is he complete code that gets the keys and values for each item in the object in the array:

```
string key = null;
string value = null;

foreach(var item in inner)
{
    JProperty questionAnswerDetails = item.First.Value<JProperty>();

    var questionAnswerSchemaReference = questionAnswerDetails.Name;

    var propertyList = (JObject)item[questionAnswerSchemaReference];

    questionDetails = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    foreach (var property in propertyList)
    {
         key = property.Key;
         value = property.Value.ToString();
    }

    questionDetails.Add(key, value);               
}
```

I can now add key and value to the dictionary