# Working with LitJson in C# in Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, litjson

I am trying to port a piece of Code from Java to C# and I am stuck in JSon parsing.
Have a look at the following Java Code

```
        mJsonObject = new JSONObject(str);
        Iterator<String> keys=mJsonObject.keys();
        while(keys.hasNext()){

            String key=keys.next();
            String value=mJsonObject.getString(key);

            mAdData.add(new AdData(key, new JSONObject(value)));


        }
```

I had a string which has verified Json format and I passed it to JSONObject and every thing was finely working in Java, but now in C# Unity I am not able to port it successful. I am using LitJson to perform this task and I have no idea how this works. I am badly stuck please help.
Thanks

Comment: Do you get an exception, what is the issue, please provide some detail

Comment: The above mentioned code is Java code I need its conversion to C#.
I have tried some but failed
Here is the code
    JsonData mJsonObject = JsonMapper.ToObject (dataObj);
    IEnumerator keys = (IEnumerator)mJsonObject.Keys;
    

Error on second line is
System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.

Answer (score 1):

The [keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json.jsonobject.keys%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method of the [JSONObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json.jsonobject%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) `class` returns an `ICollection<string>`. You can iterate an `ICollection` like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287603%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). So I would change your `while` loop into a `foreach`, like this:

```
foreach (string key in keys) {
    //whatever
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot its working. Now the next step is to get the value against the key. How can I do that? Please let me know.

Comment: Please, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19974763/get-values-and-keys-in-json-object-using-json-net-c-sharp. If an answer solves your problem, then please consider accepting it to help future visitors having the same kind of problem.

Comment: the above method does not work for me unfortunately. If my problem is solved I will definitely accept the answer.